# Disable messages and nodes

Tags: can-bus, capl

Is there a set of functions to disable/enable messages in a CANoe simulation using CAPL?

I have a node called ECM_LS that sends a message Engine_Test_Information_LS on my simulation, and I want to write a test that disables ECM_LS and ECM_LS::Engine_Test_Information_LS. Once I saw a function like disableNode() or canNodeOffline() but I do not remember clearly.

Comment: Do you mean "canOffline()" and "canOnline()"?

Comment: not really. I am looking for a function like that, but to stop only one node and not all the simulation.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to disable whole node, you can just stop sending single message.
Function for disabling is TestDisableMsg():

- long TestDisableMsg (dbMessage aMessage)
- long TestDisableMsg (dword aMessageId)
- long TestDisableMsg (char aMessageName[])

In your case it would be TestDisableMsg(Engine_Test_Information_LS);

And you can enable sending of message with TestEnableMsg(Engine_Test_Information_LS);

Or if you really need to disable whole node, you can use ILNodeControlStop and ILNodeControlStart for restarting:

- long ILNodeControlStart(char aNodeName[])
- long ILNodeControlStop(char aNodeName[])

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can....!

if you are using ILconfiguration you use
1)ILDisableMsg() function in network node.
2)For enable use ILEnablemsg().

Suppose if you are using the test module node 
1)testDisableMsg (dbMessage aMessage); in test module node
2)testEnableMSg(); for enable again the message.

Suppose if you are Using normal config(withoutil)
simply create a constant and use if condition. If that condition is ture dont

Answer (score 0):

ILNodeControlSimulationOff("ECM_LS"); //To disable the node
ILNodeControlSimulationOn("ECM_LS"); /To enable again the node